# .xml URL without any formatting in the output data

Tags: xml

I'm lost please help.

Client of mine sent over a .xml output URL (sorry can't share due to NDA). I've worked with XML data before and typically it has tags, elements, formatting, etc. And I'm able to pull it into a converter to csv file with ease. This time not so much. The output data from that url literally is just a data dump without any separators, commas, tags, elements. In fact I don't even think it technically qualifies as XML in this format. Here's an example of what the data looks like:

ex: 123streetin a nice area$1000image photo.jpglink test.com

Literally thousands of lines of unformatted data just like that. Just one long run on sentence looking thing but worse, missing spaces between the fields. It almost looks like there were separators or elements before and they were stripped out.

My goal is to pull that out into properly formatted xml and convert to .csv. Is it possible to pull it out into some kind of formatting like the example below?

```
<address>123 Street</address>
<description>in a nice area</description>
<price>$1000</price>
<image>image photo.jpg</image>
<url>test.com</url>
```

Comment: when you click "view source code" in your browser, do you get a proper xml format?

Comment: Rubens thank you! That worked. You rock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When opening XML data in the browser, it tries to render it as HTML -- usually because the server failed to server the appropriate content type header.

Most of the tags will not match any HTML elements, so it gets rendered as text. The usual symptom is to see "poorly formatted text".

In your case, it seems like you already get an XML response, so you just need to parse the actual text output. You can see it by right-clicking the page and selecting "view source code".